# How to define $D^n/S^{n-1}$?

Tags: general-topology

If $D^n$ is the unit disc on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then as the title says, how is the term $D^n/S^{n-1}$ defined? (What is the set, and what is the associated topology)

The notes I am studying defined the set $X / \sim$ for some equivalence relation, the quotient topology, the quotient map, and the topology of $X / \sim$ - but none of these fits the format of $D^n/S^{n-1}$. In general if $B$ is a subspace of $A$ how is the topological space $A / B$ defined?

Comment: The relation $x\sim y$ if $x, y\in S^{n-1}$ or $x = y$. We identify all elements in $S^{n-1}$ with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jakobian in the comments outlines the set theoretic details: $D^n/S^{n-1}$ is the set of all equivalence classes under the relation $\sim$, where $x\sim y$ iff $x = y$ or $x, y \in S^{n-1}$. Then, we put an appropriate topology on this space.

However, I think this misses some geometric intuition. You can visualize $D^2 / S^1$ as taking the unit disc, and bringing all the points around the boundary together and gluing them shut. Hopefully if this visualization is convincing enough, you should be able to convince yourself that $D^2 / S^1 \simeq S^2$.